# Webjob not processing all the messages posted on a topic subscription

Tags: azure, webjob

We have a continuous webjob listening to a topic. Whenever a message is posted on the topic the webjob picks the message (from the subscription) and processes the message. Processing takes roughly 5 min. Frequently it is happening that webjob does not process every alternative message (i.e message 1 is processed, message 2 is not processed, message 3 is processed and likewise). Messages are exactly same except for one of the ID fields in the message.

Its really confusing why this is happening. Whenever a message is not processed we see no logs for the same and it seems that it does not even come to the first line of the handler.
Any inputs on what can cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Did you specify any [filter in the subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters)?

Comment: Yes, filter is there. So the topic has multiple subscriptions and we are listening to one particular subscription where we get filtered messages. Messages are available in the subscription.

Comment: If there _is_ a filter there, the next question would be: *what's in the filter*? You might be filtering out messages. Could you post some (relevant) code? Try to create a [mcve].

Comment: No, thats what i mentioned that messages are available in the subscription so filtering logic is correct.Also its not a behaviour which happens consistently on all the environments.